# Serve static html content or dynamically render html with google cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to render dynamic HTML (via express and ejs) or at least serve some static content via the cloud functions? I've creeaded a RESTful API and would love to server the HTML/CSS/JS from the same cloud function if possible. I tried to use

```
res.render("index.ejs")
```

from my function and have added ejs to the package.json. According to express docs, specifying the file ending should require the associated view engine and render from the /views directory.

Does not work, complains that the view engine is not setup. Any ideas?

Comment: I highly recommend that you look into [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) for serving the static HTML and its [integration with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) for serving dynamically generated HTML.

Comment: thx, I will have a look at this, too. I liked to have everythign in one place though.

Comment: I figured a way to serve up HTML - in combination with checkingi the accept header, it's quite easy to detect the browser and to have the html served. function servePage(req, res)
{
 fs.readFile('views/index.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
   return console.log(err);
  }
  res.send(data);
 }); 
}

Comment: Sounds like a great self-answer! :-)

Comment: I got this working but when I deployed the function I can't get the local css and images. Any trick for this? 

@FrankvanPuffelen  and Sven